# Sphere of $n-1$ dimensions is compact

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis

I am a little stucked in here. I need to prove that for any $x_0$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $r>0$ then the following sphere
$$S_r^{n-1} (x_0) := \{ x \in \mathbb{R^n} : ||x-x_0|| \leq r \}$$
is a compact set.

First, I know that, in $\mathbb{R}^n$ a compact set is equivalent to a closed and bounded set. Second, I could prove that $S_r^{n-1}$ is a closed set because $\partial(S_r^{n-1}) \subset S_r^{n-1}$. Third, I have troubles proving that the set is bounded. I thought that it is a consequence of

$$||x-x_0|| \leq r$$

My attempt is to consider $r' \geq r$ then I define a sphere such tha

$$S_{r'}^{n-1} (x_0) := \{ x \in \mathbb{R^n} : ||x-x_0|| \leq r' \}$$

Then $S_{r}^{n-1} \subset S_{r'}^{n-1}$.
I'm not sure if I can use that fact. If There is another way of proving it or any hint, I will appreciate it.

Thank you!

Comment: But if a set $S$ is all points with some property $\le r$ and $S'$ is all points with the same property $\le r'$, and if $r\le r'$, is not $S$ surely contained in $S'$?

Comment: It's bounded because every point on the sphere is bouded by $r$ from definition of sphere

Comment: A sphere is defined by $S_r^{n-1} (x_0) = \{ x \in \mathbb{R^n} : ||x-x_0|| =r \}$. You have defined a closed ball with center $x_0$ and radius $r$. Please clarify what you really want to consider.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: use the definition of being a bounded set! A subset $A$ of a metric space $(X,d)$ is bounded when there exists some $C\in[0,\infty )$ such that $d(x,y)\leqslant C$ for all $x,y\in A$.